# Align two text views next to each other on the right of activity

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout

I have a Linear layout with orientation:horizontal
now how can i add two text view next to each other and aligned to right?

Comment: Does my solution work for you?

Answer (score 1):

use 
`android:gravity="right"` on the text views inside linear layout and it should do it.

Or if you want the whole linear layout to be right aligned, use it on the linear layout like

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right" >
   .
   .
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RelativeLayout` and and an XML like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/foo_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/question_recline" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/foo_bar"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/foo_bar"
        android:text="Text"  />
</RelativeLayout>
```